springboot3 app is unable to find liquibase changelog file
I am using Springboot3 with liquibase. Spring is unable to find the changelog file, however it is present and the path is configured correctly
project structure
src/main/java/com/example/io.akash.sharma.liquibase/LiquibaseApplication.java
src/main/resources/application.properties
src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-dml.xml

application.properties
spring.application.name=liquibase-poc
server.port=8083

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password


spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
# doesn not work even for spring.liquibase.change-log=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

db.changelog-master.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">


    <include file="/sql/changelog-dml.xml" />

</databaseChangeLog>

I am getting below error. Everything looks right, please can you help me identify my mistake.
I have the changelog in the correct directory.
Logs below
"C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk17.0.9\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.profiles.active=liquibase -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=62652:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\sharakaf\dbMacs\alert\CODE\liquibase-poc\liquibase-poc\target\classes;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\4.27.0\liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\5.9\opencsv-5.9.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.11.0\commons-text-1.11.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.4\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.14.0\commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\db\rca\commons\rca-liquibase\1.0.25\rca-liquibase-1.0.25.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-actuator-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure\3.3.0\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\3.3.0\spring-boot-actuator-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.13.0\micrometer-observation-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.13.0\micrometer-commons-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-jakarta9\1.13.0\micrometer-jakarta9-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-core\1.13.0\micrometer-core-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.2.1\HdrHistogram-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\2.0.13\log4j-over-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2.0\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\2.2.224\h2-2.2.224.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.7.3\postgresql-42.7.3.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.42.0\checker-qual-3.42.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-web-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.3.0\spring-boot-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.3.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.5.6\logback-classic-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.5.6\logback-core-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.23.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.23.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.23.1\log4j-api-2.23.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-json-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.17.1\jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.17.1\jackson-annotations-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.17.1\jackson-core-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.17.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.17.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.17.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.24\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.8\spring-web-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.8\spring-beans-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.8\spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.8\spring-aop-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.8\spring-context-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.8\spring-expression-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.8\spring-core-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.8\spring-jcl-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\spring\boot\mybatis-spring-boot-starter\2.1.4\mybatis-spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\spring\boot\mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4\mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\mybatis\3.5.6\mybatis-3.5.6.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\mybatis-spring\2.0.6\mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.1.0\HikariCP-5.1.0.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.8\spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.8\spring-tx-6.1.8.jar;C:\Users\sharakaf\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\19.21.0.0\ojdbc8-19.21.0.0.jar io.sharma.akash.liquibase_poc.LiquibasePocApplication --env.liquibase.flag=enable_liquibase
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-07-10T15:33:41.437+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] i.s.a.l.LiquibasePocApplication          : Starting LiquibasePocApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 36080 (C:\Users\sharakaf\dbMacs\alert\CODE\liquibase-poc\liquibase-poc\target\classes started by sharakaf in C:\Users\sharakaf\dbMacs\alert\CODE\liquibase-poc\liquibase-poc)
2024-07-10T15:33:41.440+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] i.s.a.l.LiquibasePocApplication          : The following 1 profile is active: "liquibase"
2024-07-10T15:33:42.401+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8083 (http)
2024-07-10T15:33:42.408+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-10T15:33:42.409+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-07-10T15:33:42.451+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-10T15:33:42.451+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 968 ms
2024-07-10T15:33:42.519+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-10T15:33:42.668+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA
2024-07-10T15:33:42.669+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-10T15:33:42.680+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2024-07-10T15:33:43.129+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to PUBLIC
2024-07-10T15:33:43.282+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.command                        : Logging exception.
2024-07-10T15:33:43.282+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.ui                             : ERROR: Exception Details
2024-07-10T15:33:43.282+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.ui                             : ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  ChangeLogParseException
2024-07-10T15:33:43.282+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.ui                             : ERROR: Exception Primary Reason:  ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
2024-07-10T15:33:43.282+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.ui                             : ERROR: Exception Primary Source:  4.27.0
2024-07-10T15:33:43.283+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] liquibase.command                        : Command execution complete
2024-07-10T15:33:43.284+05:30  WARN 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
2024-07-10T15:33:43.285+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-07-10T15:33:43.287+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-07-10T15:33:43.289+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-07-10T15:33:43.299+05:30  INFO 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-10T15:33:43.319+05:30 ERROR 36080 --- [liquibase-poc] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at io.sharma.akash.liquibase_poc.LiquibasePocApplication.main(LiquibasePocApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:259) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:257) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:245) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:190) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:199) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:168) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1436) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:234) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:212) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:297) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:249) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:190) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:199) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:168) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:256) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:242) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:114) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.lambda$getDatabaseChangeLog$0(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:129) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:199) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.getDatabaseChangeLog(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:128) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.run(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:87) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:219) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar:na]
    ... 34 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1


I see a mistake in your folder: src/main/resources/db/ chnagelog /changelog-dml.xml

@AnhTuấnNguyễn thanks it was a typo in my question, updated it. Do you see why it might not be working

@xerx593 Thanks. Tried this as well but didn't work

Hi bro, make sure the name of db.changelog-master.xml without trailing space

I have my changelog in src/main/resources/config/liquibase and my configuration looks like this: liquibase.change-log=classpath:/config/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml. You need to change your liquibase configuration properties to start with liquibase instead of spring (and perhaps add the leading slash to your path). I also have liquibase-core in my pom. I used this as a guide.

If you are using Spring Tool Suite you may try to rebuild your workspace from scratch:

Project menu -> uncheck Build Automatically
Project menu -> Clean...
In the Clean dialog -> check Clean all projects and, uncheck Start a build immediately
Restart Spring Tool Suite (File menu -> Restart)
Check again the automatic build

